# Windows C socket, read N bytes from the socket stream

Tags: c, windows, sockets

How do i read exactly N bytes from the socket stream in C on windows 10, the only function i was able to find is recv() that reads everything.

Answer (score 1):

As [the official documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv), you have to pass to the `recv()` function 4 parameters:

- `s` - The socket descriptor
- `buf` - The memory buffer which will hold the read data
- `len` - The length of the memory buffer
- `flags` - "A flag or a set of flags that influence the behavior of this function"

In particular, when the last parameter is set to the defined value `MSG_WAITALL`, the `recv()` function will complete only when one of these events occurs:

- The buffer supplied by the caller is completely full.
- The connection has been closed.
- The request has been canceled or an error occurred.

In other words, if you want to read exactly 10 bytes, you should create a 10 bytes buffer and ask the `recv()` function to return only once the buffer is full!

```
char data[10];
recv(streamSocket, data, 10, MSG_WAITALL);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Please note that, depending on the protocol used, `recv()` might discard any data that doesn't fit into the buffer. When using TCP, you can read small chunks like that and no data is lost. When using UDP however, you can of course still read a small chunk, but the rest of the packet will be discarded.

Comment: It works, thank you, ive known about MSG_WAITALL but i had no idea it meant that

Comment: Note that not all platforms support `MSG_WAITALL`, in which case the alternative is to just call `recv()` in a loop until the desired number of bytes have been received, eg: `char data[10]; char *ptr = data; size_t len = 10; do { int num = recv(streamSocket, ptr, len, 0); if (num <= 0) { /* error handling */ break; } ptr += num; len -= num; } while (len > 0);`

Comment: @FelixG You're completely right. I suggested that method because the OP did specify that the socket would be a stream socket, thanks for the clarification.